# CSV not to be exported in Magento

Tags: magento, csv

I have set the following Code within WebController.php

```
/**
* Export order grid to CSV format
*/
public function exportCsvAction()
{
    $fileName = sprintf('stores-%s.csv', date('Ymd'));
    $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/web_web_grid');
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
}
```

I don't know what is the problem that causing CSV not to be exported.

Following error is showing -

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCsvFile() on a non-object in
/var/www/projects/tmp/storelocator/app/code/local/Company/Web/controllers/Adminhtml/WebController.php
on line 0
```

Please help!
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line :

```
$grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/web_web_grid');
```

returns null. The error tells you it clearly :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCsvFile() on a non-object

Are you sure this 'adminhtml/web_web_grid' relates to a block ?

Do you have a folder/file `Web/Web/Grid.php` in the `Block` folder of the adminhtml module ?

For example, if you didn't overload the Mage_Adminhtml module, you should have a class named `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Web_Web_Grid` in the folder `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Web/Web/Grid.php` that's what the `createBlock('adminhtml/web_web_grid')` is searching for

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you calling right block(Block must be extended by Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid or it might be grid like)
then use your code

You might test by following code by putting in action (its magento core code)..........

```
$fileName   = 'customer.csv';
$content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_grid')->getCsvFile();
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
```